# MS Teams - fetch the team Ids and channel Ids in which the bot is installed

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have developed a bot in MS Teams and i want to fetch the channel Ids where the bot is installed and can send the messages.
Any ideas how to do this, thanks a lot

Comment: Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=json#fetching-the-roster-or-user-profile)? Try if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can only really do this when there's an interaction from the user, so for example when the user sends your bot a message. The best time of all, however, is when your bot is actually installed, because then you have it right from the beginning. You use the ConversationUpdate event, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#team-member-or-bot-addition).

If it's too late for that (your bot is installed already), then I'm only aware of waiting for the next message - I'm not sure if it's possible to get things like the conversation id another way.